# WCF - 403 until I restart the AppPool

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, http-status-code-403, application-pool

I have a rather curious (a.k.a. annoying) issue.

I've setup a **WCF** web service repository on my local workstation (still under development).
I've published the project under the local IIS with its own dedicated application pool: .NET v4.0.30319, Integrated pipeline mode.

In some of the webservices inside this solution I make some rest calls to other external https webservices (over the Internet).

After, let's say a day or even less, all the rest calls made by the published solution end up with 403 Forbidden error. 
If I restart the application pool under which this solution in running, all these 403 errors are gone - that is, of course, for another couple of hours or a day tops - this is the part that's driving me crazy!!!

W/o any change in the code, or anything else, if I just restart the application pool, the ws calls start working again.
Also, when I have the 403 errors, if I run the project in debug mode (VS * IIS express), the calls to the external web services are working perfectly (no 403).

I could provide samples of code, but as stated above, I don't really think this is a code related issue as, once I restart the app pool, everything starts working again...

Has anyone ever encountered such an annoying issue?

Please help!

Below are the application pool's settings.

[image]

**Later edit:**

Perhaps it's worth mentioning that for the REST calls to the external web services, I use the same generic method. Here's the code:

```
public static string GetRestCall(string requestUri, string contentType, string method, string postData, bool removeServerCerticateValidatioCallBack = true,bool byPassCachePolicy = true, 
 bool keepAliveRequest = true, string userAgent = null, string acceptHeaderString = null, string referer = null, CookieContainer cookieContainer = null, int timeOutRequest = 60000)
{
   try
        {
            if (removeServerCerticateValidatioCallBack == true)
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };
            }

        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@requestUri);

        req.KeepAlive = keepAliveRequest;
        if (byPassCachePolicy == true)
        {
            RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
            req.CachePolicy = cachePolicy;
            req.Expect = null;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
            req.Method = method;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptHeaderString))
            req.Accept = acceptHeaderString;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
            req.Referer = referer;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
            req.ContentType = contentType;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
        { req.UserAgent = userAgent; }
        else
        {
            req.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
        }
        if (cookieContainer != null)
            req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        req.Timeout = timeOutRequest;

        using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(postData);
            }
        }

        using (WebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as WebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseStream = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return responseStream;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the frequency of the calls to the external rest services? How many are generally successful before you get the 403s?

Comment: It varies from 2 up to 15. But, just looking at the logs, I've noticed that the 403 pops-up each time after 2 clients consumes exactly at the same time my ws that's calling the external ws. But the weird part is that my IIS does't reply the client with a 403, but the external ws is replying my calls with a 403. Seems like somehow a DOS or DDOS behavior, but I'm talking about at least 3 external WS that have nothing to do with each other, one of them I know for sure it's hosted on an Apache server..

But then again, why does a restart/recycle of my app pool solves this?!

Comment: OK, have you tried increasing Maximum Worker Processes from 1? And if that makes no difference setting the Idle Timeout to say 1 minute? I'm wondering if, as you say, the external server(s) is detecting multiple requests too quickly from the same process.

Comment: @spodger These are the modifications I've made to the application pool I'm using: Idle Time-Out: 1 minute; Maximum Worker Processes: 6; Recycling - Regular Time Interval(minutes): 60. I will keep monitoring the situation with these new settings.

Comment: fair enough - good luck!